# The session cannot be established after the response has started

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I saw this error in my logs, but I can't figure out how to reproduce it. It does not occur regularly.

**Exception Message:** The session cannot be established after the response has started. 
**Stack trace:**

*at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSession.Set(String key, Byte[] value)*

CustomMiddleware.cs:

```
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, AlertWriter alertWriter, AlertReader alertReader)
    {
        var sessionAlerts = context.Session.GetString(AlertKey);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sessionAlerts))
        {
            var alerts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Alert>>(sessionAlerts);
            alertReader.Initialize(alerts);

            context.Session.Remove(AlertKey);
        }

        await _next.Invoke(context);

        if (context.Response.StatusCode >= 300 && context.Response.StatusCode < 400)
        {
            alertWriter.Alerts = alertWriter.Alerts.Union(alertReader).ToList();
        }

        var serializedAlerts = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(alertWriter.Alerts);

        //ERROR IS HERE
        context.Session.SetString(AlertKey, serializedAlerts);
    }
```

In Startup.cs, `app.UseSession();` is the first app.Use... that I call. 
[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state) says that this error will occur if you *"attempt to create a new Session (i.e. no session cookie has been created yet) after you have already begun writing to the Response stream"*.

How can I avoid this error? Seems like if I try to access the session in any custom middleware, I'll have to check if the .AspNetCore.Session cookie exists?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set headers before content is sent.

Doing it before `await _next.Invoke(..)` is usually safe. But when calling it after after `_next` there is no guarantee that the middleware which is called later in the chain did or did not write to the stream.

You can circumvent it by caching the response until your middleware is done, but this may have severe performance impact as the complete stream would need to be stored in memory and then in later middleware written to the original stream. On big responses this may significantly increase the memory usage of your application.

Something like

```
using (var buffer = new MemoryStream())
{
    var body = context.Response.Body;
    context.Response.Body = buffer;
    ...
    await _next.Invoke(...);

    // set headers or session
    context.Session.SetString(AlertKey, serializedAlerts);

    // read buffer and write to body
}
```